# "&" binding to parent component from a named view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angular 1.5 application that uses component routing from ui-router 1.0.

```
.config(/*@ngInject*/($stateProvider) => {
$stateProvider
.state('efd.kbe', {
    url: '',
    abstract: true,
    template: '<div ui-view="kbe"></div><div ui-view="ala"></div>'
})
.state('efd.kbe.show', {
     url: '/kbe/{kbeId}',
     views:{
         'kbe@efd.kbe':{
            component: 'showkbe'
         },
         'ala@efd.kbe':{
            component: alaComponent.name
         }
     }
 })
.state('efd.kbe.create', {
    url: '/kbe/create',
    views: {
        'kbe@efd.kbe':{
            component: 'createeditkbe'
        },
        'ala@efd.kbe':{ }
    }
})
.state('efd.kbe.edit', {
    url: '/kbe/{kbeId}/edit',
    views: {
        'kbe@efd.kbe':{
            component: 'createeditkbe'
        },
        'ala@efd.kbe' :{
            component: alaComponent.name
        }
    }
});
})

.component('kbe', {
    template: defaultTemplate,
    abstract: true
})
.component('showkbe', {
    template: showTemplate,
    controller: controller,
    bindings: {
        onActiveStateChange: '&',
        kbeActiveState: '<'
    }
})
.component('createeditkbe', {
    template: createEditTemplate,
    controller: controller
})
```

I would like to call in the component "showkbe" the method "onActiveStateChange" that should run in the parent component "kbe", but I cant find a way to get it running. I have studied
 https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component#routed-parentchild-component-communication and the associated plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/6Vk1dN
The difference betwen my code and this exemple seems to be the named views. Could this be the cause of the incompatibility of ui-router and component bindings ?

EDIT:
I tried to add `on-active-state-change="$ctrl.foo()"` to the state efd.kbe and also to the ui-view element in the efd template, but I could not get the call in the child component "showkbe" to trigger anything in any of its parents.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.**

Comment: I checked that you are using ui routing release candidate version, and now there is a stable version [ui-router.1.0.3](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-ui-router)

Comment: I updated the version, but the behavior is the same. Thanks for the hint @The.Bear